# In Unity, Is Camera "Depth Only" option no longer available?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm using Unity 2022.3.4f1 version now. In this version, There is no "Depth Only" option in Camera Object.
But, 2021.3.19f1 version has "Depth Only" option.

I want 2D UI Image to overlay 3D Object.
But, now 2D UI Image is overlaid by 3D Object.
I want to troubleshoot this situation.

Comment: Are you using URP?